# Save update on cassandra compound primary key

Tags: cassandra, primary-key

I have a compound primarykey (uid, stale) which when I try to edit the stale boolean value gets duplicated (as the compound key can support both these combinations)

Eg:

```
1) uid-val, TRUE
```

when stale column updated to FALSE results in 2 rows of data one with older TRUE and the new FALSE

```
1) uid-val, TRUE 
2) uid-val, FALSE
```

Is there anyway to overcome this rather than with a delete before inserting the updated values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - change of the components of the primary key will lead to adding the new row...

Why not convert that column into "normal" column from partition key/clustering column? I think that you need adjust data model

Comment: Thanks Alex. Would using a materialized view be a good option ? Table 1: primary key(uid, nonboolean_col1) and mat view primary key (uid, nonboolean_col1, boolean_col2) or would the mv consider the changed boolean value as a new entry and insert it as the 2nd column.

Comment: yes - it will consider 2nd different boolean value as additional value and insert new row. MVs are just tables that are managed for you

Comment: Oh my, then what please would be the way to model to query with a boolean where clause - select col1,col2 from table where nonboolean_col3='value' and boolean_col4=False.

Comment: Also, are you sure about the 2nd different boolean value being inserted as a new row? Because I tested last night with table PRIMARY KEY (col1, uid) and a mv PRIMARY KEY ((col1, stale), uid). A unique row which changed from False to True in table has the same unique row in the mv and not one with False and one with True.